# Add suffix to filename if file exists in internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add a suffix to the filename, which counts up.

```
val file = File(it.path)
```

If the file already exists i need to add a suffix to the filename: filename(1).ext, filename(2).ext.. counting upwards.

I tried renaming the file, but it adds the suffix after the file extension: filename.ext(1)

```
      file.mkdirs()
      if (file.exists()) {
        file.renameTo(File(it.path+"(1)"))
      }

      file.createNewFile()
```

Comment: `file.mkdirs()` ??? You know what mkdir tries to do? Please explain.

Comment: `file.createNewFile()` Why are you trying to create a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider possible cases:

```
 1. "standard" case, filename with extension: abc.jpg -> abc(1).jpg
 2. no extension: abc -> abc(1)
 3. double extension, like tar.gz: -> abc.tar.gz -> abc(1).tar.gz
```

So, in all cases, we want to append suffix before the first dot occurrence OR if there is no extension at the end of a file.

```
fun appendSuffix(filename: String, suffix: String): String {
    return if (filename.contains('.')) {
        // has ext, the easiest way is to replace a first dot :)
        filename.replaceFirst(".", "$suffix.")
    } else {
        // no ext
        filename + suffix
    }
}
```

and some tests:

```
fun main() {
    println(appendSuffix("abc", "(1)"))
    println(appendSuffix("abc.jpg", "(1)"))
    println(appendSuffix("abc.tar.gz", "(1)"))
}

// output:
abc(1)
abc(1).jpg
abc(1).tar.gz
```

How to use it? I assume you know how to get the filename :).
If you need check if it should be "(1)" or "(2)" you can make simply loop, where you:

1. check if filename exists
2. append "(n+1)"
3. go back to 1

Answer (score 1):

***Updated answer :***

```
fun main() {
    val fileName = "filename.ext"
    val file = File(fileName)
    file.mkdirs()
    if (file.exists()) {
        val extension = file.extension
        var newFileName = fileName
        for (i in 1..Int.MAX_VALUE) {
            newFileName = file.nameWithoutExtension.plus("($i).").plus(extension)
            if (!File(newFileName).exists())
                break
        }
        println(newFileName)
        file.renameTo(File(newFileName))
        file.createNewFile()
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the filename contains a "." in the name itself? Like file.name.pdf for example? Wouldn't that crack your code?

Comment: I updated my answer. there is a function in kotlin which is called nameWithoutExtension (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/name-without-extension.html). you can also have the extension name of your file (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/extension.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but how can I scale this? Like how can I add 02 instead of 01 if 01 also already exists?

Comment: u r welcome, updated again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timestamp.

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS").format(new Date());
String fileName = "filename_" + timeStamp;
File imageFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "jpg", getFilesDir());
```